# PrimeNG p-calendar - disableDate format

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng, primeng-calendar

I want to disable the dates from primeNG calendar.

```
<p-calendar [(ngModel)]="dateValue" dateFormat="dd.mm.yy" [disabledDates]="[here are the dates]"></p-calendar>
```

For example I want to disable the dates from calendar except today and tomorrow.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Instead of using `disabledDates`, you should use `minDate` and `maxDate` that way :

**HTML**

```
<p-calendar [(ngModel)]="dateValue" [minDate]="minDateValue" [maxDate]="maxDateValue" readonlyInput="true"></p-calendar>
```

**TS**

```
this.minDateValue = new Date();
this.maxDateValue = new Date(new Date().getTime() + 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
```

See [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6toheo)